# Local/remote access synchronization for an ftp site

Tags: ftp, synchronization, locking

I am writing some code to update an application by fetching new dlls from an ftp site, according to a manifest file, also at the ftp site, which specifies the versions of each dll. The basic idea is, that an updater program runs at startup, which checks the manifest at the ftp site, downloads any dll's which are newer than those currently used by the application, and then starts the application and shuts itself down.

This leads to the following problem, that I am not sure of the best way to handle: Say that I want to put a new dll on the ftp site, but at the same time an updater application instance tries to read that dll. If I delete the dll, and then copy over the new one, the updater might not see the file, even though the manifest says that it should be there.

I have the idea of a sort of marker file, that will act as a synchronization object, and whose existence I and the updater instance can use as a lock, but is that not just moving the problem? There is still the time between checking if the lock is there, and making the lock, in which someone else could make the lock, and start modifying the ftp files. Plus, if some updater crashes before deleting the marker, there is no way of telling, whether the leftover marker should be deleted.

Edit: I also saw a suggestion to upload the files to another folder, and then rename the folder, since renames are supposed to be an atomic operation in ftp, but is it possible to just rename the folder to the name of an existing folder? Shouldn't the existing folder be deleted first, thus causing the same problem?

Is there a standard approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: On the FTP server, include version info in the filename. On the client, rename the file after downloading.

Comment: Thanks. I think it could work. Since the manifest specifies which dll versions to use, there is no harm in having two dll versions up at the same time. Once the new dlls are uploaded, I copy the new manifest to the site. In the overlap between versions, Clients will have to figure out, which is the newest manifest version, but that is of course doable. I guess, I'm holding out for something a little simpler, but if no other answer is coming, I will accept this one.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you'll still have the same problem with updating the manifest, although presumably it's very much smaller and so the risk is smaller. Maybe you could delete the old manifest, update the new DLLs, then upload the new manifest. Any client currently downloading the old DLLs will carry on OK, and if a new client finds the manifest is missing it can wait and retry in ten seconds or whatever. And after downloading the manifest the client could check for some end-of-file marker to be sure it's complete.

Comment: I had thought about that. I don't think, I should update the manifest. Instead the manifest name should also be versioned. The client could then start by finding the newest manifest, then download that, and the dlls that go along with it. After a while, say an hour or a day or so, all clients that had downloaded the old manifest, would have downloaded the old dlls, and any current downloads would only be of the new versions, so the old version could be deleted. To make sure that the new manifest is completely uploaded, I could create it under another name, and then do a rename.

Comment: I still think it is odd that there must be such an ad-hoc solution to this problem, which I had thought to be fairly common. But thanks anyway for your suggestion.